# VS Code outline / function list window for all opened files

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Notepad++, I use the SourceCookifier plugin, which provides me with a list of all functions of all currently opened files (grouped by file) and is updated dynamically, ie

- if a file isn't open, its contents aren't listed
- if it is open and then closed, the listed contents are dynamically updated

Settings allow you to do much more than that (and list a lot more objects if you want), but I am only interested in listing functions. (see picture)

[image]

I would like to get the same thing in VS Code.

VS Code does provide, in the Outline section of the Explorer, a function list of the **current** tab in focus, but I have not found how to have it list functions of **all** opened tabs (and have them grouped by source file).

Is it possible to have such a list displayed at all times, and grouped this way ?

Comment: somewhat related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/166923